# ListView hide some items

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I want to hide some items in ListView depending on some criteria. I found 2 solutions but none of them work. I've tryed to return empry `View` from `getItem()` method but divider is still visible. So if I hide all of the items for example it leads to a large stack of dividers. The second one was to set `View.GONE` in `getItem()` method. But ListView still reservates place for invisible items and that leads to the empty views in my list. Has anyone found a workaround for this question?

EDIT: Also I need to notice that I can't remove any data from the dataset. Adapter/ListView must only HIDE specified items.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would implement this in the following way:

1. Create a list/array inside of your adapter which will hold the indexes of the items that are going to be hidden.

   For example:

   ```
   List<Integer> hiddenItems;
   ```
2. Override your adapters `getCount()` method to return the number of
   items in your list MINUS the number of items in the collection
   mentioned in step 1.

   For example:

   ```
   @Override
   public int getCount() {
       return items.size() - hiddenItems.size();
   }
   ```
3. Override `getItem()` to return the items offset by the indexes
   contained in the collection from step 1.

   For example:

   ```
   @Override
   public Object getItem(int position)
   {
       for (Integer hiddenIndex : hiddenItems) {
           if(hiddenIndex <= position)
               position++;
       }

       // Now your regular getItem code...
   }
   ```

Comment: But what if the last item is hidden? In your case, it would raise the position b one, but there is no element left

Comment: Don't forget to sort hiddenItems if they are not not sorted. It took me many hours to fix that bug. Also as @MarianKlühspies noticed, I added some code: return position < list.size() ? list.get(position) : null;

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE:**

Yes you can `add/remove` even after you have provided the data to the adapter. Store the data in some `ArrayList<type>` and pass it to the custom adapter class.

```
ArrayList<String> dataList;

// store data in dataList 
list.setAdapter(CustomAdapter(YourClass.this, dataList));
```

---

The easiest work around is to `remove` those items from the adapter of the ListView and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. This will `remove the cells/row` of those items from the list.

```
 adapter.remove(object);
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // this will update your ListView
```

If you plan to use those items in the future in the list again, store them in separate place For example store them in a file or database, which ever suits your needs the best.

Comment: Sorry, I've already implement my own Adapter which removes items from provided ArrayList also. So I can't use remove method for this propose. Actually I need to edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me your best bet would be to either extend the ListAdapter you're using and add methods for hiding certain rows and adjust `getCount()` etc. Or you could write a wrapper adapter (you could implement the `WrapperListAdapter` interface) for use with any ListAdapters here and in the future whenever you need to hide rows.